# Cordova app with autologin feature

Tags: cordova

My app has a login screen, where user can input name and password to login.
In addition I have a checkbox called "Remember me".
If I login and play around, everything works fine. But if I restart the app, I realized that my app has got a new session id.

Thats a problem. Somehow I need to login in the backend by app start if user selected the "Remember me" checkbox by last login.

I realized that there is a token-based solution. Your backend creates a token and maps it with the session id. Than it sends the token to the client (app) which persists it in localstorage. 
How do you do it?

Comment: We're using a local storage token for just that purpose. I'm not aware of any security concerns, though we're not storing the keys to Fort Knox in our app. That said, your question is too broad for SO.

Comment: hey thanks. yes maybe the security concern subject is too broad for SO.
But I guess we can discuss the token approach.
Do you use in the backend a table where you store userid, token (maybe expireDate, createdDate)?

Comment: Yes, though I'm the front-end developer and don't have much insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is my solution:

1. I use https, checking the certificate by this plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin
2. My app is crypted with this plugin: https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file
3. The user is sending a login request via ajax (sending: username, password, device-uuid) and receives a token from the server.
4. I do same cryption in my app with the token and save it in a local sqlite database using this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sqlite-storage. The reason for the cryption is, that it is possible to copy the database.
5. On every ajax-request I send the decrypted token and the device-uuid.
6. From time to time I change the token.

Comment: In my opinion this is a very nice solution. since you send the device uuid which is unique for every device (no matter which brand) - at least I think so. i guess a attacker could not do anything even if he is able to steal the token.