# How to auto login into login page after user exits the app?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a login page via WCF restful APIs. I am logging in and now the problem after logging in if user exits in the app and try to re open the app, the app doesn't want to ask the user for credentials by storing the previous credentials. It has to automatically redirect to the another page. Any ideas, suggestions? I'm using JavaScript and HTML & Cordova.

Comment: Please use localstorege and save the user credentials  for specific time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer

[Cordova app with autologin feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760494/cordova-app-with-autologin-feature?answertab=active#tab-top)

This answer is one of the best ways to implement autologin in hybrid apps, to me.